# How to determine the destination IP of received UDP packet in C# when join multiple multicast groups

Tags: c#, sockets, udp, multicast

I'm using a single UdpClient in C# to receive packets from several multicast groups, because they are using the same port.

But the question is that how can I determine the destination IP of a received packet, that is, how can I know which multicast group the packet was from?

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

```
public int ReceiveFrom(
    byte[] buffer,
    ref EndPoint remoteEP
)
```

Gives you bytes send from remote side.
And gives information about the sender.

More details at:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdfskwcy(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thanks，but what I want is not the info of sender, I want to identify which multicast group the packet is from, in other words, the **destination IP** of this packet instead of **source IP**.

Comment: I will suggest you to use wireshark. That will help you to diagnose each and every packet that hits your n/w interface.